# Page content not loading when trying NG SERVE in console Visual Studio 2017 Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli

Im a very beginner with angular. So recently started with VS 2017 with Angular-CLI.

Two troubles am facing.

Next is when I execute the application, its not reflecting the changes until I run NG build in command. Im executing the command from windows powershell. So once the page loads or before executing if I run **NG BUILD**, when the page shows its having all the changes. Didnt understand why.

Next is when I execute **NG SERVE** from console and then execute the application, Only the title bar text showing. Nothing in the content portion or the body is simply empty. So to make it show again, I need to break the application and then **NG BUILD** and then run it shows the page as before.

These are the configuration in my package.json

```
{
    "name": "test-app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "watch": "ng build --watch"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~5.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "~5.0.1",
        "@angular/common": "~5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "~5.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "~5.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~5.0.0",
        "@types/bootstrap": "latest",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
        "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.5.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "~2.4.2"
    }
}
```

And here is the content of launchsettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54225/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "myProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54218/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you run `ng serve` and have a blank page, it's because of an error. Did you try opening the console and see the errors you had ?

Comment: I checked the developer console and there is no errors I seen.. Only some get messages showing to the JS files from Dist folder

Comment: And is the `ng serve` command returning `webpack : compiled successfully` ? Did you try making a new project and serving it to see if it works ?

Comment: Yea.. its returning Webpack :compiled successfully..

then  its looks like its not allowing further command after the above message..

Comment: So far so good then. And when you go to localhost:4200, you only have a blank page ?

Comment: Im using IIS express. And the URL Im trying is http://localhost:54225

And its the url when executing the application

Comment: Out of a curiosity, is there is any connection with scripts block in package.json??

Comment: IIS express ? For what, you backend ? Because `ng serve` launches a webserver on port 4200, so maybe you should check this page out ? And no, in package.json, the scripts are simply scripts run by npm with `npm run [script]`

Comment: Yea. Since am running from Visual studio and so the execution by default being handled by iisexpress using that url in package.json...
I checked that URL you given its saying cannot establish a connection to that url.. For that URL to work do we need to add any more info to any JSON

Comment: Hum yes, run `ng serve --port 4200` and go back to the page

Comment: OK.. Thats great... Now its does something like we run from VS after running NG SERVE. blank page shows.. 

But from the console what I found is dist/jsfile  not found.. so none of the JS files are not loading.. so I think its approaching to the issue..

Comment: How did you create your project ? with a `ng new` ?

Comment: No buddy.. Just opened the solution and executed.. So when the blank page comes (NG SERVE), I checked the source and what I found is the angular tags are not at all rendering and part of that source is like this

<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js">...

But when working fine (NG BUILD) its like rendering the tags and its being replaced. and the script uRL is like this
<script src="/dist/inline.bundle.js?v=HwYxrCRi_Mj02dge5PMMOXA5XkKkMeRp7eO2X1dIdPk"></script>

Comment: That's because building minifies the code and create vendor scripts (script with random names to avoid caching). If you didn't create the project with a ng new, I can't help you ! I don't know any piece of your code, so I can't tell you what's wrong. But if ng serve doesn't render anything, it's probably an issue you can see in your console. if it doesn't find a file like you said (dist/file), make sure you don't have a `script` tag in your `index.html`

Comment: Sorry buddy.. Thats true.. But just a little more clarfication if you dont mind.. Since I didnt created the project, can I do that ng new if the project is already there?

The issue in console is the scripts were missing in the dist folder. 
Also.. Yea there is no script tag in index.html

Comment: No problem, I'm here to help, only in the limits of what I can do :) What you can do is create a new project with `ng new PROJECT_NAME`, and move all of your components/services/modules/etc. In the `app` folder. All you will have left to do is correct the errors related to your scripts or dependencies. Then, you should be good to go !

Comment: Sure buddy... Seriously thanks a lot for your valuable time..
The issue I am facing is Im working on a project our architect initiated and its running on VM.. Anyway let me try to achieve what you suggested with in my restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Follow the same process as you've done from angular installation to 'ng serve' in another folder.
Same was the problem with me so I've tried once again same process in another folder, it works. Now no more blank pages.